# git ignore file after initial check-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

I have a visual studio project that is being tracked in Git. This is needed to pull down the source and be able to load the project. However, there are some user specific info in the .csproj files that is very annoying to keep getting checked in and replacing peoples' local changes.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add file name or mask in `.gitignore` file. `.gitignore` should be commited afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the files in the .gitignore, and then delete them from the git repo :

```
git rm .csproj
```

But beware, if there is some general configuration needed by new developpers, they'll need to get the general content themselves.